# Write CSV from MySQL?

Tags: sql, csv, mysql

I'm trying to export a table in MySQL as a CSV, but I'm having trouble. I've tried two approaches, neither of which have worked.

First:

```
SELECT * 
INTO OUTFILE '/path/to/filename.csv' 
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
ENCLOSED BY '"' 
ESCAPED BY '\\' 
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' 
FROM table;
```

Second:

```
mysqldump -u [username] -p -t -T/path/to/directory [database] [table] --fields-enclosed-by=\" --fields-terminated-by=,
```

Comment: What is wrong with the first one?

Answer (score 1):

try this example,

```
SELECT order_id,product_name,qty FROM orders
INTO OUTFILE '/tmp/orders.csv'
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
```

**[SOURCE](http://www.tech-recipes.com/rx/1475/save-mysql-query-results-into-a-text-or-csv-file/)**

Answer (score 0):

**SELECT order_id,product_name,qty FROM orders
INTO OUTFILE '/tmp/orders.csv'
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'**

is correct if it is not worked then try to avoid path of the file....just give file name and after execution look resulted file in '**/var/lib/mysql/dbname**'.